# Ms Teams OnlineMeeting anonymous user joining authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

Online Meeting Event is created using MS graph api with attendees outside of organization and not part of azure ad as well.Meeting invite will be sent to attendees mail ids automatically.so is there any way to authenticate whether user entering into lobby as guest will be as attendees added while creating event.

The useCase will be for Scheduling virtual Interview.so basically the attendee will not be part of organization and azure ad as well.

Comment: You can try the following option from admin end (not the API) which helped me to move ahead:

At the Microsoft Teams Admin Center (admin.teams.microsoft.com/meetings/settings) > Meetings > Meeting Settings
Needed to turn on Participants > Anonymous users can join a meeting > It will take a while to come to effect.

Answer (score 0):

Now the MS Graph API cannot determine whether the guest or anonymous user is an attendee.

But we can identify it by other method.

The login behavior of attendees is as follows: when you have logged in to the attendees account, you will display a login interface that is different from anonymous users. If you are not logged in to the attendees account, you can first enter an anonymous name and then click sign in to log in to the account. The meeting will recognize your attendees, not an anonymous user.

[image]

You can require the interviewees to sign in with the email id you invited. In this way you can determine whether this user has joined this meeting as an attendee or not.